# MySQL, Adding two columns recursively after comparing them

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This is my table data:

```
   ID   val   Coulmn1  Column2
   1     1     0.4000    0
   1     10    0.1250    0    
   1     18    0.1429    0
   1     26    0.2500    0
   2     13    0.0000    0
   2     21    0.1429    0
   2     29    0.2500    0
   2     34    0.3333    0
   3      6    0.3333    0
   3      7    0.20      0
   3     14    0.2500    0
   3     22    0.1429    0
   3     33    0.2500    0
   4      8    0.2000    0
   4     15    0.1250    0
   4     23    0.1429    0
   4     31    0.0000    0
```

I want to add to columns if column1 is greater than column2 in the same row and if the final value is max it should be applied to all the rows of the same id.

I have following scenario.

```
if (Column1 > Column1 ) 
then (Column1 + Column1 )
else (Column1 )
```

Output is Can be:

```
       ID   val   Coulmn1    Column2
       1     1     0.4000    0.4000    
       1     10    0.1250    0.4000         
       1     18    0.1429    0.4000 
       1     26    0.2500    0.4000 
       2     13    0.0000    0.39285
       2     21    0.1429    0.39285
       2     29    0.2500    0.39285
       2     34    0.3333    0.39285
       3      6    0.3333    0.3333
       3      7    0.20      0.3333
       3     14    0.2500    0.3333
       3     22    0.1429    0.3333
       3     33    0.2500    0.3333
       4      8    0.2000    0.2
       4     15    0.1250    0.2
       4     23    0.1429    0.2
       4     31    0.0000    0.2
```

any supportive link or solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please add the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    t1.id, t1.val, t1.column1,
    t2.col as column2
from yourtable t1
join (
    select 
        max(tmp.col) as col, 
        id
   from (
       select 
           yourtable.*,
           @col := case when @grp = id then 
                        case when @col < column1 then @col + column1 else @col end
                        else column1 end as col,
           @grp := id
       from yourtable
       cross join (select @col := 0, @grp := null) t
       order by id, val
   ) tmp
   group by id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

This is almost for all databases.

And here is demo for `mysql`:[<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96a054/7)

Comment: thanks for quick response 

@10086 
but have a look to the id=2 the column2 value is "0.3333" but it should be "0.1429+0.2500= 0.39)

any suggestion?

Comment: perfect
Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

You want the `max()` window function:

```
select t.*, max(column1) over (partition by id) as column2
from t;
```

MySQL does not support window functions.  You can do this using a `join` and `group by`:

```
select t.*, tt.column2
from t join
     (select id, max(column1) as column2
      from t
      group by id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id;
```

Comment: nopes actually its not a simple max function, its a running sum as well

Comment: @Nomanuddin . . . Looks much more like a `max()` to me.  I admit that id = 2 doesn't quite fit, but ids 1, 3, and 4 definitely do.

Comment: actually if id 1,3,4 have also same type of data like id = 2 then max() will not work. Thank you @Gordon Linoff